# Can't import dataframe from share point (ERROR)

Tags: pandas

I'd like to import a dataframe, but receiving a "read" error.
What am i doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Did you try to read the error and google the documentation? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: it should be `sheet_name` instead of `sheetname`? Read the docs here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html